# Django Field Choices

Tags: django-models

Given below is my Model definition and I have added this module part of the Admin. I'm trying to create new row and while selecting value '3' or any other value for Duration field(listed as select fields), I get the following error.- "Value 3 is not a valid choice".

Please provide your inputs.

**Model Definition**
NO_OF_HRS = (
        ('1','One'),
        ('2','Two'),
        ('3','Three'),
        ('4','Four'),
        ('5','Five'),
        ('6','Six'),
        ('7','Seven'),
        ('8','Eight'),
        ('9','Nine'),
        ('10','Ten'),
        ('11','Eleven'),
        ('12','Twelve'),
    )

```
YR_MONTH = (
("Y", "Year"),
("M", "Month"),
)

POS_STATUS = (
("A", "Active"),
("C", "Closed"),
)

datecreated   = models.DateTimeField()
volposition   = models.CharField(max_length=300)
roledesc      = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
noofhours     = models.IntegerField(blank = True,null = True)
Qualreqt      = models.CharField(max_length=8000)
Duration      = models.IntegerField(choices=NO_OF_HRS,blank = True,null = True)
Durationyrmon = models.CharField(choices=YR_MONTH,max_length=10)
posstatus     = models.CharField(choices=POS_STATUS,max_length=1)
teamrelation  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `choices`, the first value of the tuple is the value that will be stored in the database and the second value is the value that will be shown in the admin.

In `NO_OF_HRS` the values are strings (for example '1', '2') but it is a `models.IntegerField` so the values should be integers. That's why you're now getting an error.

Comment: Please click on the checkmark next to this answer if it indeed answers your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Opened a ticket on django with fix and dirty fix:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24897